# Frenkel-Kontorova model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, mathematical-physics, many-body

The Hamiltonian of the Frenkel-Kontorova model is given by 
\begin{eqnarray}
H&=&\sqrt{2}\hbar\sum_{i=1}^{N}\{(\hat{n}_{i}+\frac{1}{2})-\frac{K}{\sqrt{2}\hbar}\cos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{\hbar}{2^{1/8}}(\hat{a}_{i}+\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i})+\mu i)\}\nonumber\\
&-&\sqrt{2}\hbar\sum_{i=1}^{N}(\hat{a}_{i}+\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i})(\hat{a}_{i+1}+\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i+1}).
\end{eqnarray}
where $\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i}$ and $\hat{a}_{i}$ are the annihilation and creation operators satisfying [$\hat{a}_{i},\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{j}$ ] = $\delta_{ij}$,     [$\hat{a}_{i},\hat{a}_{j}$ ]=[$\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i},\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{j}$ ]=0. I would like to know whether the above Hamiltonian has exact solution? How to analyze the term $\cos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{\hbar}{2^{1/8}}(\hat{a}_{i}+\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i})+\mu i)\}$?